# How sort data when use row_number() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2012, row-number

I want to sort data when using the `row_number()` function or other way around.
I sort new "sort_type column" when "e_type column" changed last status (when s_type <> e_type).

Raw data:

```
req_no   | seq   | s_date     | e_date     | s_type    | e_type   |
---------+-------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
001      | 1     | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 |  01       | 01       |
001      | 2     | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01       | 02       |
001      | 3     | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  02       | 02       |
001      | 4     | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  02       | 01       |
001      | 5     | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01       | 01       |
001      | 6     | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01       | 01       |
001      | 14    | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  04       | 03       |
001      | 15    | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03       | 03       |
001      | 16    | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03       | 03       |
001      | 17    | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03       | 03       |
```

I get this result from my query right now:

```
req_no | seq  | s_date     | e_date     | s_type | e_type | sort_type
-------+------+------------+------------+--------+--------+----------
001    | 1    | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 |  01    | 01     | 1
001    | 2    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01    | 02     | 1

001    | 3    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  02    | 02     | 2
001    | 4    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  02    | 01     | 2

001    | 5    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01    | 01     | 3 
001    | 6    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01    | 01     | 4 
001    | 14   | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  04    | 03     | 1
001    | 15   | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03    | 03     | 2
001    | 16   | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03    | 03     | 3
001    | 17   | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03    | 03     | 4
```

But I want the result to be like this:

```
req_no | seq  | s_date     | e_date     | s_type | e_type | sort_type
-------+------+------------+------------+--------+--------+----------
001    | 1    | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 |  01    | 01     | 1
001    | 2    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01    | 02     | 1

001    | 3    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  02    | 02     | 2
001    | 4    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  02    | 01     | 2

001    | 5    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01    | 01     | 3 (or not show)
001    | 6    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-02 |  01    | 01     | 4 (or not show)
001    | 14   | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  04    | 03     | 5 (or 3)
001    | 15   | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03    | 03     | 6 (or not show)
001    | 16   | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03    | 03     | 7 (or not show)
001    | 17   | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-03 |  03    | 03     | 8 (or not show)

002    | 1    | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 |  01    | 02     | 1
002    | 2    | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 |  03    | 03     | 2
002    | 3    | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 |  03    | 03     | 2
002    | 4    | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 |  03    | 04     | 2
002    | 5    | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 |  04    | 04     | 3 (or not show)
```

This is my SQL Server query:

```
SELECT
    a.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e_type ORDER BY req_no, seq) AS sort_type
FROM
    tb_listtype a
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I can't understand what you want, which logic is applied to calculate those *(or not show)*  values?

Comment: And also, where req_no = 002 records come from? You don't have them on the original raw data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help WITH 
Try this

```
;With mytmpTable as
(
SELECT
    a.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e_type ORDER BY req_no, seq) AS sort_type
FROM
    tb_listtype a
)
select * from mytmpTable where e_type=3 and sort_type>3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select req_no, seq, s_date, e_date, s_type, e_type,
       sort_type - sort_type_temp [sort_type]
from (
    select req_no, seq, s_date, e_date, s_type, e_type,
           sum(sort_type) over (partition by req_no order by s_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) sort_type,
           case when s_type <> e_type then -1 else 0 end sort_type_temp
    from (
        select req_no, seq, s_date, e_date, s_type, e_type,
               case when s_type <> e_type then 1 else 0 end sort_type
        from MY_TABLE
    ) a
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `order by`:

```
SELECT a.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e_type ORDER BY req_no, seq) AS sort_type
FROM tb_listtype a
ORDER BY req_no, sort_type;
```